# Export WPF Metro Charts

Tags: wpf, charts, export

I'm using the Modern UI (Metro) Charts for WPF (http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) in my application and I'd like to export the charts I'm displaying in PDF format (or JPEG, PNG if it's simpler). I don't have any clue how to do it and cannot find any post related to that. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to render your UI to an image and save it:

```
public MemoryStream GenerateImage
    (Visual vsual, int widhth, int height, ImageFormat format)
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder = null;

    switch (format)
    {
        case ImageFormat.JPG :
            encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            break;
        case ImageFormat.PNG:
            encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            break;
        case ImageFormat.BMP:
            encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            break;
        case ImageFormat.GIF:
            encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
            break;
        case ImageFormat.TIF:
            encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
            break;
    }

    if (encoder == null) return null;

    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = this.RenderVisaulToBitmap(vsual, widhth, height);
    MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
    encoder.Save(file);

    return file;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.